# Convert keys in inner hash to keys of outer/parent hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash, say,

```
account = { 
  name: "XXX", 
  email: "xxx@yyy.com", 
  details: { 
    phone: "9999999999", 
    dob: "00-00-00", 
    address: "zzz" 
  } 
}
```

Now I want to convert `account` to a hash like this:

```
account = { 
  name: "XXX", 
  email: "xxx@yyy.com", 
  phone: "9999999999", 
  dob: "00-00-00", 
  address: "zzz"
}
```

I'm a beginner and would like to know if there is any function to do it? (Other than merging the nested hash and then deleting it)

Comment: So the `merge` and `delete` can be done like this also: `account.merge(account.delete(:details))` pretty simple !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
account.map{|k,v| k==:details ? v : {k => v}}.reduce({}, :merge)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a short solution..the kind that I wanted :)

Comment: It should be noted that the the performance (both in time and memory) of this option is significantly worse than a minimal `account.merge(account.delete(:details))` as proposed by @Deep above. Your solution is `O(3n)` while Deep's solution is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement a generic `flatten_hash` method which works roughly similar to [`Array#flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) in that it allows to flatten Hashes of arbitrary depth.

```
def flatten_hash(hash, &block)
  hash.dup.tap do |result|
    hash.each_pair do |key, value|
      next unless value.is_a?(Hash)

      flattened = flatten_hash(result.delete(key), &block) 
      result.merge!(flattened, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

Here, we are still performing the delete / merge sequence, but it would be required in any such implementation anyway, even if hidden below further abstractions.

You can use this method as follows:

```
account = { 
  name: "XXX", 
  email: "xxx@yyy.com", 
  details: { 
    phone: "9999999999", 
    dob: "00-00-00", 
    address: "zzz" 
  } 
}

flatten(account)
# => {:name=>"XXX", :email=>"xxx@yyy.com", :phone=>"9999999999", :dob=>"00-00-00", :address=>"zzz"}
```

Note that with this method, any keys in lower-level hashes overwrite existing keys in upper-level hashes by default. You can however provide a block to resolve any merge conflicts. Please refer to the [documentation of `Hash#merge!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) to learn how to use this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Again, it's merging and deleting. I wanted to know if there was any single ruby function for it. Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: There is no method like `Array#flatten` for Hashes in Ruby's core since its semantic are not universally clear or applicable to every case. With the `flatten_hash` method you come pretty close your what you desire. Still, as I said, even if there would have been be a core method, it would still use `merge` and probably `delete` internally.

Comment: Nice! Keerhana, you need a recursive solution like this for the general case where there are multiple levels of nested hashes. (Sorry, no shortcuts.) If there is just one level or nesting, as in your example, simplifications are possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Each value of `account` may be a hash whose values are not hashes**

```
account.flat_map { |k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.to_a : [[k,v]] }.to_h
  #=> {:name=>"XXX", :email=>"xxx@yyy.com", :phone=>"9999999999",
  #    :dob=>"00-00-00", :address=>"zzz"}
```

**Case 2: `account` may have nested hashes**

```
def doit(account)
  recurse(account.to_a).to_h
end

def recurse(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) { |(k,v),a|
    a.concat(v.is_a?(Hash) ? recurse(v.to_a) : [[k,v]]) }
end

account = { 
  name: "XXX", 
  email: "xxx@yyy.com", 
  details: { 
    phone: "9999999999", 
    dob: { a: 1, b: { c: 2, e: { f: 3 } } },
    address: "zzz" 
  } 
}

doit account
  #=> {:name=>"XXX", :email=>"xxx@yyy.com", :phone=>"9999999999", :a=>1,
  # :c=>2, :f=>3, :address=>"zzz"}
```

**Explanation for Case 1**

The calculations progress as follows.

One way to think of [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), as it is used here, is that if, for some method `g`,

```
[a, b, c].map { |e| g(e) } #=> [f, g, h]
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, `f`, `g` and `h` are all arrays, then

```
[a, b, c].flat_map { |e| g(e) } #=> [*f, *g, *h]
```

Let's start by creating an enumerator to pass elements to the block.

```
enum = account.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: {:name=>"XXX", :email=>"xxx@yyy.com",
  #     :details=>{:phone=>"9999999999", :dob=>"00-00-00",
  #     :address=>"zzz"}}:each>
```

`enum` generates an element which is passed to the block and the block variables are set equal to those values.

```
k, v = enum.next
  #=> [:name, "XXX"]
k #=> :name
v #=> "XXX"
v.is_a?(Hash)
  #=> false
a = [[k,v]]
  #=> [[:name, "XXX"]]

k, v = enum.next
  #=> [:email, "xxx@yyy.com"]
v.is_a?(Hash)
  #=> false
b = [[k,v]]
  #=> [[:email, "xxx@yyy.com"]]

k,v = enum.next
  #=> [:details, {:phone=>"9999999999", :dob=>"00-00-00", :address=>"zzz"}]
v.is_a?(Hash)
  #=> true
c = v.to_a
  #=> [[:phone, "9999999999"], [:dob, "00-00-00"], [:address, "zzz"]]

d = account.flat_map { |k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.to_a : [[k,v]] }
  #=> [*a, *b, *c]
  #=> [[:name, "XXX"], [:email, "xxx@yyy.com"], [:phone, "9999999999"],
  #    [:dob, "00-00-00"], [:address, "zzz"]]

d.to_h
  #=> <the return value shown above>
```